# getJSON success function out of scope

Tags: ajax, jquery, getjson

I just have started writing AJAX functions using jquery. Here i am calling `myfunction()`. where check.php is returning `{"count":1}` or `{"count":0}` for which myfunction is always returning `retval=false` . But for `{"count":1}` it should return true. I dont know where i am wrong. Below is the code i am using.

```
function myfunction(){
var retval=false;
if($('#tag').val() != ''){
    var query=$( "#tag" ).val();
    $.getJSON("check.php",{
        q: query
    },function(data){
        if(data.count==0){
            $('#formerrormsg').html('Error msg');
        }
        else{
            retval=true;
        }
    });
}
return retval;
}
```

Please Help me to understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because, `$.getJSON(..)` is **asynchronous**. The below is what jQuery doc says about the third parameter you are passing (`function(data){...}`):

> *success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)*: A **callback** function that is executed if the request succeeds.

The function which set `retval` to true is executed when the AJAX call succeeds; not when you call `myfunction()`

There are two way you could get around this:

- Make your AJAX call synchronous; the function wont return until the response is received. (Not a great idea, UI might freeze)
- Modify your code -- the asynchronous way. Typically, call the function (that would ideally be depending on the return value) from within the "success-function" defined as the 3rd parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It is an AJAX (asynchronous) request so `return retval;` is returning before the AJAX success function executes, hence always returns false. You need to change your implementation to wait for that request before returning and using `retval`.